# Convert String data into Binary stream

Tags: ada

I have a simple Ada application for sending and receiving data over sockets. I now need to modify this to create a packet/stream using a string read from a file. The string is the binary representation of the message body.

So a string of 1111000011110000 should be sent as 2 bytes F0 F0. The data size is known and fixed.

Where I'm struggling is to parse and convert the string in the correct way, every 8 characters is a binary representation of 1 character.

What is the correct way to do this in Ada, either parsing the string or maybe reading it from the file in a different format (currently using Get_Line which reads a string)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the remapping using an appropriate instantiation of `Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO`.

You would have to enclose the eight zeros and ones in `"2#"` and `"#"` to tell that the number is in base 2, and remove the information telling that the output is in base 16.

Comment: Thanks. I used Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get ("2#" & byte_string & "#", int_value, last)